# Highstock : Shared tooltip except for one series

Tags: highcharts

Concerning http://jsfiddle.net/5gjne/10/ I would like simply hide the "red" range series (range2) into tooltip, how to make this?

```
                tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [disable mouse tracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking) on that series it'll be excluded from tooltip.

```
{
    name: 'Range',
    data: ranges2,
    type: 'arearange',
    lineWidth: 0,
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    color: 'red',
    zIndex: 0,
    enableMouseTracking: false //<--add this
},
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gjne/11/).